# Linking and sorting two arrays

Tags: matlab

I want to link, join and sort two arrays that are linked to another two arrays, like so:

`A1 = [5, 4, 8, 6]` linked to

`A2 =[10, 15, 12, 14]` and

`B1= [5.5, 6.5, 8.5, 4.5]` linked to

`B2=[11.5, 25.5, 16.5, 49.5]`

I want to join A1 with B1 into C1 and A2 with B2 into C2 and when I sort C1, C2's numbers should move with the numbers of C1, since they are linked. More clearly:

```
C1=[5, 4, 8, 6, 5.5, 6.5, 8.5, 4.5] 
C2=[10, 15, 12, 14, 11.5, 25.5, 16.5, 49.5]

D1=[4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 8, 8.5 ] % sorted C1
D2 = [15, 49.5, 10, 11.5, 14, 25.5, 12, 16.5 ] % since 4 is linked to 15, 4.5 is linked to 49.5 etc...
```

I am actually trying to do in matlab what is very simple in excel, you have two columns, sort one and the other follows.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
C1=[A1, B1];%join them
C2=[A2, B2];

D=[C1;C2];
D1=sort(D(1,:)); % this does not work
```

I think I have to use find somewhere, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sort` was the right idea. You can obtain the indices of the sorted array by getting the second return value, see the documentation on [`sort`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html).

So, the quite simple solution should be:

```matlab
D = [C1; C2];         % Build D
[~, idx] = sort(C1);  % Sort C1, but only use the indices of the sorted C1
D = D(:, idx)         % Rearrange D column-wise by the sorted indices

D =
    4.0000    4.5000    5.0000    5.5000    6.0000    6.5000    8.0000    8.5000
   15.0000   49.5000   10.0000   11.5000   14.0000   25.5000   12.0000   16.5000
```